# Issues With ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a plot that will give me distance of apartments based on latitude and longitude. I need the latitude / longitude in the axes and the distance plotted in between. I have done quite a few of such and all work fine. In this case however, i find the error

> Removed 414 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

There is no NA in the data set. I believe it has to do with the limits I am setting for the distance because if I change the c(0,1500, 4000, 6500) values, some data are visible. I just cannot find the right sets of values for the same. Is there a trouble shooting way ? Thanks

```
ggplot_transaction <- ggplot(real_estate_data, 
    aes(x=real_estate_data$Longitude, 
        y=real_estate_data$Latitude, 
        colour = cut(real_estate_data$Nearest_Distance, breaks=c(0, 1500, 4000, 6500)))
     ) + 
  geom_point() + 
  labs(colour = "Distance", title="Nearest Distance Distribution", 
       x="Longitude", y="Latitude") + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('blue', 'green', 'red'),
                    limits=c('(0,1500]', '(1500,4000]', '(4000,6500]'))
```

Comment: Use e.g. `str(cut(real_estate_data$Nearest_Distance, breaks=c(0, 1500, 4000, 6500)))` or `table(real_estate_data$Nearest_Distance, breaks=c(0, 1500, 4000, 6500)))` to get an idea of how many values you get in each category. `range(real_estate_data$Neares_Distance)` will give you the data range. Anything outside 0 and 6500 is currently set to NA.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$` in the `aes` just use the variable name

Comment: summary(real_estate_data$Nearest_Distance)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  23.38  289.32  492.23 1083.89 1454.28 6488.02 Also, there is no NA values. If I change the range to breaks=c(0, 290, 1455, 6500), I have only the values <290 (111 obs.) plotted on the graph. Rest values (>1455,104 obs and in between 199 obs.) not getting plotted. seems like a size issue. Thanks